# Javascript: Constructing Objects

Tags: javascript

I'm a bit of a javascript noob, but I have a general question that has been bothering me. Lets take an example:

If I hop into a JS console on Chrome, I can easily browse the `window` object. `window` seems to list a lot 'class types', so to speak. For example, `window.CSSPrimitiveValue` is one such property. When I evaluate `window.CSSPrimitiveValue` in the console, I get back what looks like a constructor (possibly):

```
function CSSPrimitiveValue() { [native code] }
```

So it looks like the function was implemented in some native language. No matter. Naturally, I want to construct one of these things, like so:

```
var test = new CSSPrimitiveValue();
```

But then I get an error:

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

I suspect that either I am calling the constructor incorrectly, or it isn't a constructor at all. I'm a pretty big JS noob about this, but is there any way for me to manually construct one of these objects? What would be the method to going about that?

Comment: In some cases I was able to create my own object that has the same properties and methods as the object I wasn't allowed to create and it worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Any function that is written in JavaScript can be a constructor when called using the `new` keyword. As you already noticed the function you are dealing with is *native*, i.e. written in C or C++ (probably C++ since Chrome's JavaScript engine is written in C++, too). Native functions/objects can have specific behaviour such as your case where you cannot use it as a constructor - there's nothing you can do.

That "function" doesn't even have a `.call()` method, you you also cannot call it on an object you created before (not that it would be very useful as it wouldn't have the proper [[Prototype]] set)