# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor – Using Bonsai.JS in Backbone.JS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, bonsaijs

I'm still new to js and I'm trying to fit bonsai.js into a backbone app.

I'm following this guide here:  https://github.com/iamdustan/bonsai-demos , and trying to 'Separate Things Out' by putting the animation into a separate file titled `hero-animation.js`, but I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor` on the first line of `hero-animation.js`

This is called in my Backbone router, and is working fine...

```
homeAnimation: function() {
    bonsai.run(document.getElementById('heroContent'), {
    url: 'hero-animation.js',
    width: 500,
    height: 400
  });
}
```

Here is what I have in hero-animation.js which is resulting in an error on line 1:

```
var rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
rect
.fill('random')
.addTo(stage)
.attr({
  x: stage.width - rect.attr('width'),
  y: stage.width - rect.attr('height')
})
.animate('0.5s', {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950876/javascript-constructing-objects may help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like you forgot to include `bonsai.js`.

Initially, `Rect` is [an "interface"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814683/what-is-rect-function-for-in-javascript), which means it can't be used as a constructor, and Bonsai overrides it for its own purposes.