# What is Rect function in Chrome/Firefox for?

Tags: javascript, function

I've stumbled upon `Rect()` function, which is present in both Firefox and Chrome (but not IE 10):

```
typeof Rect; // "function"
Rect;        // function Rect() { [native code] }
```

But this function isn't accessible neither directly, nor as a constructor:

```
Rect();     // TypeError: Illegal constructor
new Rect(); // TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

What is the purpose of this function?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Geometry.jsm/Rect

Comment: The documentation (as linked above) does not list a constructor or provide other guidance on how to use such type .. considering the errors above, this should likely be included/addressed in answers.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 the link you provided describes a deep Gecko-specific feature unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Rect` is an interface defined in [Document Object Model (DOM) Level 2 Style Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Style/css.html#CSS-Rect) to be used when dealing with CSS `rect()` in DOM bindings (such as the Javascript DOM bindings in a browser).

As you noticed you cannot call it as a constructor yourself, but objects implementing this interface are returned by various functions [e.g. `.getRectValue()`](http://jsfiddle.net/t3vdj/):

```
function doSomething(v) {
  if (v instanceof Rect) {
    ...
  }
  else {
    ...
  }
}
doSomething(window.getComputedStyle(elem, null).
  getPropertyCSSValue(styleProp).getRectValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

These days you can create a DOMRect:

```js
var myDOMRect = new DOMRect(x, y, width, height);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect/DOMRect