# Does 'Rect' have a constructor function?

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to find any reference to it in the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Geometry.jsm/Rect#Method_overview), but is there a public constructor function for the `Rect` "class"? What arguments does the function take?

**Edit:** It seems like trying to call `Rect()` (with or without parameters) results in a `TypeError: Illegal constructor`: http://jsfiddle.net/IQAndreas/a55hG/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is Rect() function for in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814683/what-is-rect-function-for-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You need DOMRect: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMRect/DOMRect

```
new DOMRect(x, y, width, height)
```

Answer (score -1):

The constructor is `new Rect(left,top,width,height)`

Any fewer arguments will result in those many fields not being set. eg. `new Rect(1,2,3)` will return a Rect object with no height

Screenshot here : http://puu.sh/81KSa/e225064bec.png

Comment: You cannot use the Mozilla Rect object in jsFiddle. It's only usable in Firefox after you run Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Geometry.jsm");